# Shuffle the characters

Tags: c#, shuffle, stringbuilder

I need to shuffle the characters in the way that at each iteration, the odd characters of the string are combined and wrapped to its beginning, and the even characters are wrapped to the end.

```
public static string ShuffleChars(string source, int count)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("source is null or empty");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("source is white space");
        }

        if (count < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("count < 0");
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            string tempOdd = string.Empty;
            string tempEven = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    tempOdd += source[i];
                }
                else if (i % 2 != 0)
                {
                    tempEven += source[i];
                }
            }

            source = tempOdd + tempEven;
        }

        return source;
    }
```

This works perfectly fine BUT, when count = int.MaxValue then it is in an seemingly endless loading
The task given to me says that I will have to optimize this, and people adviced using StringBuilder, so I came up with something like this:

```
public static string ShuffleChars(string source, int count)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("source is null or empty");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("source is white space");
        }

        if (count < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("count < 0");
        }

        StringBuilder sourceString = new StringBuilder(source);
        StringBuilder tempOdd = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
        StringBuilder tempEven = new StringBuilder(string.Empty);
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        {
            tempOdd.Clear();
            tempEven.Clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < sourceString.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    tempOdd.Append(sourceString[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    tempEven.Append(sourceString[i]);
                }
            }

            sourceString = tempOdd.Append(tempEven);
        }

        return sourceString.ToString();
    }
```

As far as I understand when I clear tempOdd and tempEven, sourceString gets cleared as well, and that is why when I shuffle the string more than once it returns me empty string.
May be there are other ways to optimize this?

Comment: You're probably supposed to calculate a substring, not generate the entire 2 GB * 2 of string bytes.

Comment: Test einter `IsNullOrEmpty` or `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`. Using both makes no sense, since the latter includes the former.

Comment: if you know length in advance you can preallocate 2 arrays `char[]` and set individual values into them without doing costly division by increasing index by 2 (`i++` -> `i+=2`) and than call `new string(buff)`. Also such solution potentially can be vectorized

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are setting `sourceString = tempOdd.Append(tempEven);`. I.e., `sourceString` is now a reference pointing to the same `StringBuilder` object than `tempOdd`! Then you are clearing `tempOdd`, which is in fact is the same object as `sourceString`. And btw., you have inverted even and odd. `i % 2 == 0` is even.

Instead, append both, the odd and even string to `sourceString` after having cleared it.

```
sourceString.Clear();
sourceString.Append(tempOdd).Append(tempEven);
```

Note that `Append` returns the `StringBuilder` itself. Therefore, this is equivalent to

```
sourceString.Clear();
sourceString.Append(tempOdd);
sourceString.Append(tempEven);
```

---

Strings are immutable. Therefore, when you are manipulating strings, you are always creating new strings. E.g., when you add a character to `tempOdd`, this creates a new string object having a length longer by one character. Then it copies the old string into the new one and appends the character. This generates a lot of new objects and involves a lot of copying.

`StringBuilder` works with an internal mutable buffer. Since the size of these buffers remains the same at each iteration, the characters can be appended to the already existing buffers, with no object creation (except for the initialization phase) and copying of strings involved.

Therefore `StringBuilder` is more efficient than `string`.

---

But there are more optimizations you can make, as @JL0PD already pointed out. The length of the even and odd parts is known in advance. Therefore, we can copy the characters to the final places and thus avoid having to concatenate the result at the end.

Also, this solution reuses the same character buffers at each iteration. To achieve this, we must swap the two buffers at each iteration to make the previous result the new source.

```
public static string ShuffleChars(string source, int count)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source)) {
        throw new ArgumentException("source is null or empty or white space");
    }
    if (count < 0) {
        throw new ArgumentException("count < 0");
    }

    // Initialize the wrong way, since we are swapping later.
    var resultChars = source.ToCharArray();
    var sourceChars = new char[source.Length];
    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        // Swap source and result. This enables us to reuse the same buffers.
        var temp = sourceChars;
        sourceChars = resultChars;
        resultChars = temp;

        // We don't need to clear, since we fill every character position anyway.
        int iOdd = 0;
        int iEven = source.Length / 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                resultChars[iEven++] = sourceChars[i];
            } else {
                resultChars[iOdd++] = sourceChars[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return new String(resultChars);
}
```

Comment: But what if source.Length is an odd number?

Comment: The the first index 0 is always even. There will be one even more than odds. Therefore, the  number of odds is `source.Length / 2` with truncates the result. The first even is at index 0 + number of odds. This is precisely what this code does. Btw., the last element, which is now even, will never change its position. Try it or make a sketch with say 5 characters and you will see!